# How to add new key to map in Firestore

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore

I want to add new key to a map. memberFees is a field of a document under collection named Faculty
I want to store only the key of each member fee inside the memberFees map.

Here is an example of my memberFees map:

[image]

I only added that keys in the example manually.

This is what I did:

```
writeBatches.get(batchIndex).update(db.collection("Faculty")
                .document(faculty.getId()), "memberFees/" + memberFeeId, true);
```

This code throws an error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid document reference. Document references must have an even number of segments, but Faculty/7DEj7mlTPBf3cVSCtQO3/memberFees has 3
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentReference.forPath(DocumentReference.java:81)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When updating a nested field, use `.` to separate the field names. Your code uses `/`, which Firestore interprets as a subcollection.

So:

```
writeBatches.get(batchIndex).update(db.collection("Faculty")
    .document(faculty.getId()), "memberFees." + memberFeeId, true)
                                     //
```